# Excel 2010 IF() statement assistance

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I need assistance converting this to an Excel formula or VBA script.  Let me know if you have questions.  It needs to run on each row starting at row 2 until row 30.  This is an example of what would be on row 2.  Also, if any character other than 1 or 2--to include nothing or null--is in J2, then M2 needs to remain blank as well.

```
if (J2="1" || J2="2"){
    if (I2="*(AE)*"){
        M2="(AE)"
    }
    else{
        if(I2="*(OT)*"){
            M2="(OT)"
        }
        else{
            if(I2="*(OT SP)*" || I2="*(OTSP)*"){
                M2="(OT SP)"
            }
            else{
                M2="F"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VBA, the equivalent to your example is:

```
If Range("J2").Value = "1" Or Range("J2").Value = "2" Then
    If Range("I2").Value Like "*(AE)*" Then
        Range("M2").Value = "(AE)"
    End If
ElseIf Range("I2").Value Like "*(OT)*" Then
    Range("M2").Value = "(OT)"
ElseIf Range("I2").Value Like "*(OT SP)*" Or Range("I2").Value Like "*(OTSP)*" Then
    Range("M2").Value = "(OT SP)"
Else
    Range("M2").Value = "F"
End If
```

But to make this loop from rows 2 to 30, we'll add a simple row variable and loop:

```
theRow = 2

Do
    If Range("J" & theRow).Value = "1" Or Range("J" & theRow).Value = "2" Then
        If Range("I" & theRow).Value Like "*(AE)*" Then
            Range("M" & theRow).Value = "(AE)"
        ElseIf Range("I" & theRow).Value Like "*(OT)*" Then
            Range("M" & theRow).Value = "(OT)"
        ElseIf Range("I" & theRow).Value Like "*(OT SP)*" Or Range("I" & theRow).Value Like "*(OTSP)*" Then
            Range("M" & theRow).Value = "(OT SP)"
        Else
            Range("M" & theRow).Value = "F"
        End If
    End If

    theRow = theRow + 1

Loop Until theRow = 31
```

Comment: I got it working based on your script.  Now that I see exactly how everything is set up, I was able to add even more conditions.  I also added `Application.EnableEvents = False` at the start of the loop and `Application.EnableEvents = True` at the end of the loop to prevent infinite looping.